# Figure out what sends SIGTERM to my process

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm running debian docker container at google cloud run
(gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6+build2) 10.2.1 20210110, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2).

Something sends SIGTERM to my app and it dies.
There is no obvious reason why.
How can figure out what and why kills my container app?

App runs some C-based stuff and exactly the same container with exactly the same input works on local Macbook w/o problem. The problem is reproducible only at google cloud run.

What can i check?

UPD:

```
Application exec likely failed
terminated: Application failed to start: not available
```

that's all I can find useful at Google cloud run logs. I can see that app (python) receives SIGTERM.

- I've added signal handlers but it didn't help, no extra info.
- I've added `dmesg` output at SIGTERM handler, no extra info. The last message is about initialised network interface. Don't see any traces of root cause
- 100% it's not timeout or stuff like that since longer requests work fine

Comment: Review the Cloud Run logs. Check the time of the last HTTP request to your service and the time your container was terminated. Most likely your container was not processing requests and your container can be terminated. Edit your question with those details.

Comment: Are you trying to run code compiled on your Mac on Cloud Run? They use different processor architectures. The error **Application exec likely failed** might indicate that.

Comment: Thanks,I've tried with DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64, same failure. App is python, it's not compiled during docker build, Dockerfile installs python deps only.

Comment: Edit your question with details. Your question states **App runs some C-based stuff**.